# CloudSQL / WordPress Multi Site 3.6 - Error establishing a database connection

Tags: php, wordpress, google-app-engine

I have an existing GAE Application that I have white listed for PHP and want to get WordPress Multi-Site running on it.  The site is up and running on the local development machine.  The problem happens after I deploy it to the app engine cloud it gives `Error establishing a database connection` in the web browser.

When I disable Multi-Site and stick with a single WordPress config it works fine.

Unfortunately the Log Console doesn't list any error and other than the error I get in the browser I have nothing else to go on.  I'm not certain what could be the issue.  I followed the configuration used by [Frankie](http://frankie.bz/#wordpress-multisite-on-google-app-engine-php-beta) who has it working.

None of the changes to enable Multi-Site seem to change how the database connects.  Kinda odd behavior IMO.  Any thoughts on how to fix/trouble shoot this?

Comment: does enabling WP_DEBUG in the wp-config.php file give you any more information?

Comment: I never got around to testing that Stuart.  I appreciate the comment.  I ran into a problem enabling SSL or hosting non-primary domains and after trying everything I could think of and it not working I moved the application to a VPS.  I even posted a question here and on the App Engine Group and never got a response.  As expected everything just works on the VPS.